# ESP8266 Mongoose OS, can't push/receive data to Google Cloud IoT

Tags: mongoose, esp8266, google-cloud-iot

I have built and flashed successfully my ESP8266 and I can also see the print outs in the console. I followed the official tutorial (https://mongoose-os.com/docs/mongoose-os/cloud/google.md) without any errors or problems.

But somehow I can't receive or push data from/to Google IoT Core. The device is registered (connection allowed) and I see the IoT API request counts on the dashboard.

Can anyone see the issue or experience the same?

**Device registry:**

[image: Device registry]

**Topic and subscription:**

[image: topic and subscription]

**IoT Core state history:**

[image: IoT Core state]

**Api dashboard (131 requests):**

[image: api requests]

**MOS console:**

[image: mos console]

- tested a second device (ESP8266)
- tested with a different computer
- tested with a different account

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved**

I did the tutorial a couple of times with different devices and computers...

I don't know why or how, I have to re-add my wifi credentials after all again, into the MOS console. Since then is working perfectly. I did the same with the other devices on the other computer, and it's working as well.